# Rails: closing a custom modal window after opening through ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, modal-dialog

I'm having trouble closing the modal window... I can't even test an alert if I'm click within the modal window:

```
$ ->
  $('#Close').on "click", ->
    alert("testing")
```

This is the content within the modal window

```
#Root
  #Bg
  #Main
    #Info
    #MainControls
      #Close{style: "cursor:pointer;"}
        %a.CloseButton
          %i X
```

My modal window is being rendered through this:

```
$('body').append('<%= j render partial: "trips/quick_view" %>');
```

In one of my views:

```
= link_to trip.id, quick_view_trips_path, remote: true
```

So the partial is being rendered, when someone clicks on the `quick_view_trips_path`. How do I close this window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click event on `#Close` is not binded. Because when `$('#Close').on "click", ->` code is running, there is no `#Close` div.

You should bind event like this,

```
$('body').on 'click', '#Close', ->
```

Comment: Oh this works! Thanks! I know I didn't ask this, but how do I close the modal window that you helped me in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469560/dynamic-content-in-ajax-while-rendering-partial-views/34472440#34472440 I don't think I just can hide the #Root container, (show/hide). I want to close and erase all data