# dynamic content in ajax while rendering partial views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, partial-views, unobtrusive-javascript

How do I get dynamic content when user clicks on different links?

**views/dashboard/index.html.haml**

```
.container
  - @trips.each do |trip|
    = link_to trip.id, quick_view_trips_path, remote: true
```

I'm pretty sure the `quick_view_trips_path` is incorrect as all the links are this:

```
<a href="/trips/quick_view">1</a>
<a href="/trips/quick_view">13</a>
<a href="/trips/quick_view">51</a>
```

Somehow I need to make these links dynamic, and then when user clicks on it, the modal window would be dynamic too.

If I replace `quick_view_trips_path` with just `trip`

```
= link_to trip.id, trip, remote: true
```

Nothing happens, and the url changes to the correct url, but my modal window doesn't get rendered through ajax. Here's an example of what the url looks like now:

```
<a href="/trips/slug-title-url-correct">1</a>
```

In addition to what I'm trying to accomplish with dynamic content, is there a way to maybe change my url like so:

```
<a href="/trips/slug-title-url-correct?quick_view=on">1</a>
```

Is it possible to get `?quick_view=on` appending to end of URL and make everything work again?

Here are the rest of my code:

**views/trips/quick_view.js.erb**

```
$('body').append('<%= j render partial: "trips/quick_view" %>');
```

**views/trips/_quick_view.html.haml**

```
.root-container
  = @trip.title
  = @trip.image
  = @trip.more_details
```

This doesn't work either right now, as my application returns `undefined method`

**routes.rb**

```
resources :trips do
  collection do
    get 'quick_view'
  end
end
```

**trips_controller.rb**

```
def quick_view
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # quick_view.html.erb
    format.js # quick_view.js.erb
    format.json { render json: @trip }
  end
end
```

Do I need to add anything to this controller as well to ensure the correct content will be generated through the partial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this way,

1. Path

   ```
   link_to trip.id, quick_view_trips_path(:js, trip_id: trip.id), remote: true
   ```

   This will render, `<a href="/trips/quick_view.js?trip_id=1">1</a>`
2. Controller

   ```
   def quick_view
     @trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id])
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html # quick_view.html.erb
       format.js # quick_view.js.erb
       format.json { render json: @trip }
     end
   end
   ```

   It will respond `views/trips/quick_view.js.erb` file